# Android nfcv.transceive() command codes

Tags: android, nfc

I am working on a mobile application that should write and read NFC tags.
I have a chip M24LR64ER from ST.
I am trying to transfer an array of bytes, which indicates the flags, command and data.

Communication is established, but data is not transmitted.

Where can I find information about command codes and flags?

```
byte[] command = new byte[3 + mes.length];
                           command[0] = 0x00; // Flags
                           command[1] = 0x21; // Command
                           command[2] = 0x00; // Number of block
                           for(int i = 3; i<command.length; i++)
                           {
                               command[i] = mes[i-3];
                           }
nfcv.connect();
byte[] conf = nfcv.transceive(command);
```

Comment: What's the length of `mes`?

Comment: I am also looking for he same.